# Data analysis using MapReduce in MongoDb vs a Distributed Queue using Celery & RabbitMq

Tags: python, mongodb, mapreduce, celery, distributed-computing

I am currently working on a project which involves performing a lot of statistical calculations on many relatively small datasets. Some of these calculations are as simple as computing a moving average, while others involve slightly more work, like Spearman's Rho or Kendell's Tau calculations.

The datasets are essentially a series of arrays packed into a dictionary, whose keys relate to a document id in MongoDb that provides further information about the subset. Each array in the dictionary has no more than 100 values. The dictionaries, however, may be infinitely large. In all reality however, around 150 values are added each year to the dictionary.

I can use mapreduce to perform all of the necessary calculations. Alternately, I can use Celery and RabbitMQ on a distributed system, and perform the same calculations in python.

My question is this: which avenue is most recommended or best-practice?

Here is some additional information:

1. I have not benchmarked anything yet, as I am just starting the process of building the scripts to compute the metrics for each dataset.
2. Using a celery/rabbitmq distributed queue will likely increase the number of queries made against the Mongo database.
3. I do not envision the memory usage of either method being a concern, unless the number of simultaneous tasks is very large. The majority of the tasks themselves are merely taking an item within a dataset, loading it, doing a calculation, and then releasing it. So even if the amount of data in a dataset is very large, not all of it will be loaded into memory at one time. Thus, the limiting factor, in my mind, comes down to the speed at which mapreduce or a queued system can perform the calculations. Additionally, it is dependent upon the number of concurrent tasks.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible to say without benchmarking for certain, but my intuition leans toward doing more calculations in Python rather than mapreduce. My main concern is that mapreduce is single-threaded: One MongoDB process can only run one Javascript function at a time. It can, however, serve thousands of queries simultaneously, so you can take advantage of that concurrency by querying MongoDB from multiple Python processes.

Comment: I decided to build into the application the ability to do both, so that I could benchmark later. When it is complete, I will post my findings here.

You are correct about the single-threadedness of the MongoDB MapReduce engine. However, please correct me if I am wrong, but I believe there is also a write lock on each MongoD instance. Since a server usually has only one mongod instance, then if for each distributed queue, I need to write at least once (possibly 3 times) to the database, then wouldn't the bottleneck be more dependent on this?

Comment: MongoDB does have a single write lock per server (per database starting in 2.2). In practice writes are fast and the lock is very very rarely a bottleneck, as long as the data you update fits mostly in memory.

This is in comparison to executing Javascript functions, which is not necessarily fast.

So I'm concerned that executing JS will be a bottleneck, but highly doubt that MongoDB's write throughput will be.